# How do I display data from Ms access in my application within VB 2008 for a specific User in my databse

Tags: vb.net

I am building this application within Vb 2008 that will allow users to login to their account (after having registered first) and view their information which has been stored in a database in MS Access. So far I have created the login and registration form, and the view profile form, but I want to know how on the users information from the data. I know that i will need to somehow send  the id value  of the user that has logged in from the login from to the view profile form,but how would I go about doing that. 
Please if you could help I would really appreciate it
This is the code for my login form :

```
   Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Login
 Dim ObjConnection As OleDbConnection

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim obj As New Profile
    obj.StringPass = "SELECT ID FROM Members WHERE username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' "
    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If txtPassword.Text = "" Or txtUsername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' Both fields was supply
        ' Check if user exist in database
        ' Connect to DB
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\My_db.accdb"


        'conn.Open()
        'MsgBox("Susscess")

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

        'Open Database Connection
        sqlCom.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

        If sqlRead.Read() Then
            Home.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        Else
            ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
            ' Throw an error message
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            'Clear all fields
            txtPassword.Text = ""
            txtUsername.Text = ""

            'Focus on Username field
            txtUsername.Focus()
        End If



    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    'User clicking on cancel button only clears field
    ' and refocus to first field
    txtUsername.Text = ""
    txtPassword.Text = ""
    txtUsername.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    Register.Show()
End Sub


End Class
```

This is code for my register for

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Register
Dim ObjConnection As OleDbConnection
    Private Sub MembersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As    System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    MembersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.MembersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.My_dbDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Register_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ObjConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\My_db.accdb")
    ObjConnection.Open()

End Sub

Private Sub btnRegsiter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRegsiter.Click
    If txtForename.Text = "" Or txtSurname.Text = "" Or txtDate.Text = "" Or txtHeight.Text = "" Or txtWeight.Text = "" Or txtUsernameRegister.Text = "" Or txtPasswordRegister.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else

        If txtRe_type.Text = txtPasswordRegister.Text Then

            Dim StrSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Members ([Forename], [Surname], [Date Of Birth], [Height], [Weigth], [Address] ,[Email], [Telephone No], [Username], [Password] ) VALUES (@ParForename, @ParSurname, @ParDate, @ParHeight, @ParWeigth, @ParAddress, @ParEmail, @ParTelephone, @ParUsername, @ParPassword)"
            Dim ObjCommand As New OleDbCommand(StrSQL, ObjConnection)

            ObjCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParForename", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtForename.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParSurname", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtSurname.Text()
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParDate", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtDate.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParHeight", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtHeight.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParWeigth", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtWeight.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParAddress", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtAddress.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParEmail", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtEmail.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParTelephone", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtTelephone.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParUsername", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtUsernameRegister.Text
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParPassword", OleDbType.Char).Value = txtPasswordRegister.Text
            ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Registration Succesful")
            Login.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Your passwords do not match, please try again", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Login.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of security concerns in your code that really should be addressed, but that notwithstanding, you just need to read the user id as part of the login procedure.

Currently you are just assuming validation on the fact that there is something to read, `If sqlRead.Read() Then`, rather than actually reading and storing a value (the user id) from the result set.

If you modify your SQL to, for example, `SELECT user_id from ....` and instead you made a call to `sqlCom.ExecuteScalar()` the return value would be the user_id which you could then store say in a session variable or some other persistent storage so that the id is available on the profile page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, but how exactly would I do that?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: In terms storing the value that sqlCom.ExecuteScalar() returns in a variable that I can access on the profile page